# What is happening with this filter:drop-shadow/translate effect in chrome and safari compared to firefox?

Tags: html, css

Basically I have a few images as buttons on my site, some of them with complicated transparency, so drop-shadow is great for an effect when a user hovers over them - which works great in firefox but...
In Chrome I get a weird stuttering thing happening which seems to acknowledge the actual border of the image like a box-shadow would, and in Safari I get a strange decrease in the blur (I think). I don't have IE installed.
What is happening here? Is this just a limitation of those browsers? Are there any work-arounds you know of?

[CodePen Example (please test in those browsers mentioned!)](https://codepen.io/JonHerbert/pen/regMqb?editors=1100)

```
img {
   width: 50%;
   -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 10px 10px #2f4f4f);
   -ms-filter: drop-shadow(0px 10px 10px #2f4f4f);
   -o-filter: drop-shadow(0px 10px 10px #2f4f4f);
   -mos-filter: drop-shadow(0px 10px 10px #2f4f4f);
   filter: drop-shadow(0px 10px 10px #2f4f4f);
   transition: all ease-in-out 300ms;
}

img:hover {
   -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 37px 20px #2f4f4f);
   -ms-filter: drop-shadow(0px 37px 20px #2f4f4f);
   -o-filter: drop-shadow(0px 37px 20px #2f4f4f);
   -mos-filter: drop-shadow(0px 37px 20px #2f4f4f);
   filter: drop-shadow(0px 37px 20px #2f4f4f);
   transform: translate(0px, -10px);
}
```

Comment: You can pad the image to fix the transition cut-off and then move the image back to its original location with a negative margin: `padding: 100px; margin: -100px` [Example pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOWVNr?editors=1100). Also, if you are using `position: absolute` then the padding won't cause a positioning problem at all, just negate it with a negative number for `left / right` etc

Comment: Thank you, I also realized it was an image problem following jamies answer. But like my solution yours still has a strange effect in safari - a reduction in blur

Comment: Odd, I guess you just need to make sure it just doesn't look horrible in IE11 and Safari and leave it at that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED...At least for chrome**

The problem stemming from chrome was that the image crop of the png was right to the edge, so when transitioning to a different state chrome would show this with a big block of grey, but adding padding, in my case of about 50px, to the image solved this issue and even allowed me to have an initial drop-shadow, which is needed for the button to stand out! I would also imagine that adding a fair amount of extra transparent space to the image in photoshop would have a similar effect. However Safari still stutters even with a transition of linear, I think this is a browser issue. I don't even want to know what this looks like in IE...

```
padding: 50px;
```

[Chrome fix for highly cropped transparent image](https://codepen.io/JonHerbert/pen/yOWVyr?editors=1100)

Comment: It works in Edge, but IE11 doesn't support filters [check support here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters). As far as I can see, the only prefix needed is `-webkit-`. The other filter prefixes you have don't seem to exist, so wont help in any browser.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive this is just the limitations of -webkit-filters. I have always had issues transitioning blurs and drop-shadows in CSS, regardless of browser. The only thing I have ever really seen remedy the stuttering is setting the easing to linear. That *usually* smoothens it out (but only slightly). I think in your case your better sticking to the classic box-shadow and giving your img a border radius of 100%. Like so

```
img {
  width: 50%;
  border-radius:100%;
  box-shadow:0px 10px 10px;
  transition: all linear 300ms;
}

img:hover {
 box-shadow:0px 10px 40px 20px;
}
```

Example
https://codepen.io/jcoulterdesign/pen/d21ebb198cb67c9de60f05dfe12ff650/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Didn't even think of checking the transition. Alas this solution won't work for me as the planet in the codepen was just a random image, my actual ones have very awkward geometry - plus safari and chrome seem to have very different ideas about what should happen with border-radius. However you did help me realize that if I add padding to the img this does solve the weird cutoff problem - which may have something to do with the image size - meaning in photoshop perhaps padding out the png would solve this issue. Still no non-hover drop though.

Comment: Ha, no problem! Interestingly enough, if you remove the initial drop-shadow state, the transition becomes smooth again. Like this: https://codepen.io/jcoulterdesign/pen/15f79b2c2533b9c7ae5293836ab0aa62/ Looks like it has issues transitioning from one drop shadow to another, but not from no drop shadow